# how to print subsets of an array with a specific length in java

Tags: java, arrays, subset

i want to print subsets of an array with array length n and subset length k.
for example ,you have {1,2,3} and you must print {1,2} {1,3} {2,3} each in a different line and sorted.(plus you must print {1,2} before {1,3})
I searched the web but they were using arraylists which it's not allowed.
i appreciate if someone please help with this problem.

Comment: Please show us some code, i.e. what have you done so far and where did you get stuck. StackOverflow is not about answering general questions or doing the coding for free, but the community will gladly help you with specific problems. Thanks, and welcome!

Comment: Is the input array sorted? Can the input array contain duplicate entries?

Comment: the array doesn't have duplicate entries.and the array isn't sorted.

Comment: I don't even know where to start.i haven't written any code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main we sort the array and call the recursive method called loopy_loop. If this a standard to new for you, you can ask here for a custom sort too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] source = {0,8,2,3,1,9,5,6,4,7};
    int k = 3, n = 10;
    int[] destination = new int[k];

    // first the sorting
    Arrays.sort(source);


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        System.out.print(source[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();

    if (k > 0)
        loopy_loop(source, destination, 0, 0);

}
```

This is a recursive function. The level follows value of (int)k and determines both the position to be filled in the destination[] and also the "depth" of the recursion.

```
public static void loopy_loop(int[] source, int[] destination, int level, int startIndex) {

    for (int i = startIndex; i < source.length - destination.length + level + 1; i++) {
        destination[level] = source[i];
        if (level == destination.length - 1)
        {
            String rez = String.valueOf(destination[0]);
            for (int j = 1; j < destination.length; j++)
                rez += ", " + destination[j];
            System.out.println("{"+ rez +"}");
        }
        else
            loopy_loop(source, destination, level + 1, i + 1);
    }

}
```